# Cloth Simulation Refuses to Settle

Tags: cloth-simulation, collision

I'm trying to bake a clothing simulation for my character animation, but the shirt geometry continues to move infinitely. I've tried multiple setting combinations, but the mesh refuses to settle. I've even tried tweaking my collider object's settings and still no luck. It's creating this weird ripple effect.

[image]

[image][image][image]

Is it possible that the scale of my model has something to do with it? It's scale to real world size, 180 cm (5'11 ft).

I was wondering if anyone knows any possible solutions that could work for me. Thank You for help.

Comment: Hi! Welcome to StackExchange. If you can provide a .blend file so we can reproduce the setting, that would be great. https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/658/including-a-blend-file